# zf2 entity with joins

Tags: zend-framework2, entity, mapper

I need to combine information from several tables.
In case of using entity I should create all possible fields as properties + setters/getters for them.
But on saving object - I should split / unset all properties which is not in main table.

Possibly there is more "true" way to deal with it, without using doctrine etc.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you, I would take a closer look to Hydrators:

[ZF2 docs on hydrators](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.stdlib.hydrator.html)

Create a new class that implements the HydratorInterface:

```
namespace Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator;

interface HydratorInterface
{
    /**
     * Extract values from an object
     *
     * @param  object $object
     * @return array
     */
    public function extract($object);

    /**
     * Hydrate $object with the provided $data.
     *
     * @param  array $data
     * @param  object $object
     * @return void
     */
    public function hydrate(array $data, $object);
}
```

You need to implement 2 functions:

```
extract($object);
```

Extract will create an array from an object.

```
hydrate(array $data, $object);
```

Hydrate will create an object from an array.

When you do a select you can have all fields in 1 array, so there you have no problem to put it in the object. When extracting, you want it split up. You could implement extract in such a way:

```
public function extract($object)
{
    return array(
        'tbl1' => array(
            'fld1' => $object->getFld1(),
            'fld2' => $object->getFld2(),
            'fld3' => $object->getFld3(),
        ),
        'tbl2' => array(
            'fld4' => $object->getFld4(),
            'fld5' => $object->getFld5(),
        ),
        'tbl3' => array(
            'fld6' => $object->getFld6(),
            'fld7' => $object->getFld7(),
            'fld8' => $object->getFld8(),
            'fld9' => $object->getFld9(),
        ),
    );
}
```

When you then extract the data, you can pass each group of data to the correct table for insert or update.